# How to reference here with Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

This is my code snippet:

```
public NaturalNumberTuple toSet() 
{
    int newTuple[] = new int[tuple.length];
    boolean checkIfYouHadToRemoveSomething = false;
    for(int i : newTuple){
        newTuple[i] = tuple[i];
    }
    for(int i : newTuple){
        for(int j : tuple){
            if(newTuple[i] == tuple[j]){
                NaturalNumberTuple placeholderTuple = remove(tuple[j]);
                newTuple[i] = tuple[j];
                checkIfYouHadToRemoveSomething = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(checkIfYouHadToRemoveSomething){
        return placeholderTuple;//Problem
    } else {
        return new NaturalNumberTuple(tuple);
    }
}
```

The method is returning a new `NaturalNumberTuple` without the given Number (here `tuple[j]`).
My `toSet()` method should give me the same Array as I'm giving to it but with only one occurrence per number.
My problem is in the line marked with (//Problem).
The Problem is that `placeholderTuple` is not defined as a variable. I know it isn't, but if I write at the beginning of my method:

```
NaturalNumberTuple placeholderTuple;
```

and at the line where I originally defined my placeholderTuple:

```
placeholderTuple = remove(..);
```

it gives me an error that `placeholderTuple` may not been initialized yet.

I know why I'm getting those errors but I really don't know how to fix that.
If anyone is trying to optimize my code with `ArrayList`s, please don't because I'm not allowed to use them (not sure if they would help here but at other code snippets they would).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of your method, write :

```
NaturalNumberTuple placeholderTuple = null;
```

This will keep this variable visible till the end of the method, and initialize it to a default value.

Then, inside the loop yo change :

```
NaturalNumberTuple placeholderTuple = remove(tuple[j]);
```

to

```
placeholderTuple = remove(tuple[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize it in the begining of the code as:

```
NaturalNumberTuple placeholderTuple = null;
```

And in your loop, just initialize it without redefining like `placeholderTuple = remove(tuple[j]);` and it should work.

I think your code will always return the last entry of newTuple which is similar to tuple, so it doesnt makes sense to me. If you just want to remove very first match, you could do without two loop like:

```
placeholderTuple = remove(tuple[0]);
```